# how to search a csv file for a perticular Word without manually opening it

Tags: c#

In C# how to search a csv file on the file share for a particular Word without manually opening it.   and if the Word exists "do something" and if not " do something else".  I want to include this step to already existing SQL Server Job.

Comment: You must open a file to see what's inside it. There's no other way. That being said, there are ways to open a file in SQL Server.

Comment: Some OS will index but few give programs access to that index. Not sure any of them keep a persistent index of a file share either. I wonder if they're asking basically how to automate the built-in OS ability to perform search without writing search code by hand.

Comment: Do you have any code that you wish to show us? You need to open the file, then use `String`'s various methods to look through the content of the file (or more precisely, the line) to see if the word is in it.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot scan content of a file without reading it:

```
string content = File.ReadAllText(path);
if (content.Contains("word"))
{
    // Text is found
}
else
{
    // Text is not found
}
```

You might consider using a regex:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(content, @"\bword\b", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
{
    // Word is found
}
else
{
    // Word is not found
}
```

Comment: If you're going to read the entire file in one go, using a Regex versus Contains isn't going to make much of a difference!

Comment: Contains matches "anotherwordinfile" and the Regex does not, it matches "another word in file".  If the file is big I recommend reading it one line at a time.